# Need to release the memory used by unused spark dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, memory, pyspark

I am not caching or persisting the spark dataframe. If I have to do many additional things in the same session by aggregating and modifying content of the dataframe as part of the process then when and how would the initial dataframe be released from memory?

Example:

I load a dataframe DF1 with 10 million records. Then I do some transformation on the dataframe which creates a new dataframe DF2. Then there are a series of 10 steps I do on DF2. All through this, I do not need DF1 anymore. How can I be sure that DF1 no longer exists in memory and hampering performance? Is there any approach using which I can directly remove DF1 from memory? Or does DF1 get automatically removed based on Least Recently Used (LRU) approach?

Comment: why do you think you have to clear the memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how spark work. Dataframes are lazy ... the only things stored in memories are the structures and the list of tranformation you have done on your dataframes. The data are not stored in memory (unless you cache them and apply an action).

Therefore, I do not see any problem in your question.

Comment: Thanks. If I have applied an action on DF1 then DF1 has data. Now I assign it to DF2. Then what happens to DF1 with data in memory?

Comment: @Bonson I said, it is not stored in memory unless you cache it AND apply an action. Did you cache it ? if so, just need to `unpersist`. otherwise, there is nothing in memory

Comment: Thank you for the response. To clarify my understanding - When the action command is executed, based on the plan, the DF is loaded into memory, actions executed and then the DF with the aggregated data gets removed from memory (Immediately). Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: @bonson it's based on map reduce processes. Most of the data manipulation are physical. Spark improves the map process using memory for some action. But never ever will the whole dataframe be stored in memory.

Comment: If it's true that the dataframe is not stored in memory, then why, when I follow a similar example as asked in the question, does my ganglia report show  150 GB ram used? I even told Spark to persist the dataframe as 'DISK_ONLY', but still the ram on my cluster is all used up and performance is very bad- I think I need to make this a new question with graphs. . .

Comment: @NathanTAlexander Because Spark uses memory to work faster than only with map reduce. But the memory is only used while resolving the action. Then it should be released automatically. The dataframe will not be stored in memroy, it will be processed in memory.

Comment: @NathanTAlexander, were you able to solve your mem problem?  I also have a similar scenario (i.e., not using cache) but still getting mem space issue when my pyspark code runs for more than 8 hours)

Comment: A Pantola see the additional answer I just added

Answer (score 0):

Prompted by a question from A Pantola, in comments I'm returning here to post a better answer to this question. Note there are MANY possible correct answers how to optimize RAM usage which will depend on the work being done!

First, write the dataframe to DBFS, something like this:

```
spark.createDataFrame(data=[('A',0)],schema=['LETTERS','NUMBERS'])\
    .repartition("LETTERS")\
    .write.partitionBy("LETTERS")\
    .parquet(f"/{tmpdir}",mode="overwrite")
```

Now,

```
df = spark.read.parquet(f"/{tmpdir}")
```

Assuming you don't set up any caching on the above df, then each time spark finds a reference to df it will parallel read the dataframe and compute whatever is specified.

Note the above solution will minimize RAM usage, but may require more CPU on every read. Also, the above solution will have a cost of writing to parquet.